# Microsoft word opens every document when I click the application

Tags: ms-word

For some reason, when I click to open Microsoft word or go to open any documents that would cause Microsoft word to open, every word file that is on my computer starts opening and my Microsoft word immediately stops responding but continues to open every document. Does anyone know why this occurs or knows how to fix it?

Comment: Are you on OSX or Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this once: when Word crashed and I restarted it, it would open whole bunch of documents. I figured it happened because I never actually closed the Word itself, only closed the current document (while the Word application itself kept running), so when Word finally restarted after crash, it reopened all documents that were accessed since the previous start of the application.

As far as I remember, I used "brute force" approach to deal with the problem: I let the Word open everything it wanted (which took a while - several minutes at least), and when it finally was done, I manually closed each and every opened Word file, then closed the Word itself, restarted it and it was fine.

Oh, one more thing: all of that was happening on Mac, but I don't think it makes a lot of difference.

Hope that helps!

Comment: THAT WORKED!! THANK YOU SOSOSOSOOSOSOSOSOOSSOOSSOOSOSOOSSOSOSOSOSOSOSOOSOSOSOSOS MUCH

Comment: OK, glad I could help! You can help me by upvoting the answer when you have enough reputation (15 is required for voting) :)